# Java "foreach" not working...nullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, nullpointerexception, collision-detection

```
Point bl = new Point(Guy.x, Guy.y + Guy.height);
Point br = new Point(Guy.x + Guy.width, Guy.y + Guy.height);

for(Tile p: platforms){
            if (p.y == br.y && br.x >= p.x && bl.x <= p.x + p.width) {
                isOnPlatform = true;
            }else{
                isOnPlatform = false;
            }

   }
```

The console says "NullPointerException" when I run that piece of code. Why isn't this working?

I already defined/initalized the variable `Tile[] platforms`. Also, when I run it, the `Guy` isn't falling down.

Also, when I do this, it works:

```
//for(Tile p: platforms){
    if (platforms[1].y  == br.y && br.x >= platforms[1].x && bl.x <= platforms[1].x + platforms[1].width) {
                isOnPlatform = true;
            }else{
                isOnPlatform = false;
            }

 //  }
```

But, I have 2 other `platforms` and I will add like 20 more. I don't want to have to do that to every `platforms`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: _What is "NullPointerException"_...At least make some effort.

Comment: Where does the NullPointerException occur (line number)? You can see it in the stack trace.

Comment: check your platforms[0] element

Comment: hover your mouse on the nullpointerexception tag you added to your question. Then click "info" in the appearing popup. Or use google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The foreach loop iterates through all the elements (including null), so if you have platforms array of length e.g. 10, and only 2 elements inside, then p.y will cause NPE (null pointer exception) since p is null when index == 2. You would have to change your code to avoid looping on null elements:

```
for (Tile p : platforms) {
  if (p == null) {
    continue; // or break, whatever is better in your case
  }
  if (p.y == br.y && br.x >= p.x && bl.x <= p.x + p.width) {
    // ...
  }
}
```